# How can I get Xcode 8 to auto-generate provisioning profiles from the command line?

Tags: xcode, provisioning-profile, ios-provisioning, xcode8

I've just set up my projects in Xcode 8 to use the new automatic provisioning. I'm trying out my command-line builds (using `xcodebuild` to build `.xcarchive` and `.ipa` files [kind of like this](http://www.thecave.com/2014/09/16/using-xcodebuild-to-export-a-ipa-from-an-archive/)). For each project that I haven't actually opened in Xcode 8, though, the command-line archive fails with invalid provisioning. When I open the project in Xcode 8 and go to the General tab of the project editor, it shows a spinner in the code signing section for a moment and says something about generating a provisioning profile, and then shows everything as ready to go. Then I run `xcodebuild` again and it works great.

My question: is there a way to trigger that auto-generation / setup magic from the command line?

Comment: Did you ever solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Fastlane Tools](https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane).

In particular if you want generate a provisioning profile you have to follow the below steps:

1. via [produce](https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/tree/master/produce) create the App ID on Dev Center;

`fastlane produce app_name <APP_ID> -u <USERNAME_DEV_CENTER> -a <BUNDLE_ID> -q <APP_ID>`

2. via [sigh](https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/tree/master/sigh) you can generate, download and install the provisioning profile

`fastlane sigh -u <USERNAME_DEV_CENTER> -a <BUNDLE_ID> -q <FILE_NAME>.mobileprovision`

In theory you can follow only the second step, but if there isn't an App Id, starts a prompt to create it.

In your case when you open Xcode, there is a creation and installation of a provisioning profile using your wildcard. So, when you build the system found this valid provisioning profile.